# Can I generate an interrupt in PHP? (INT 3, to halt the debugger)

Tags: php, debugging, interrupt

On Intel platforms, interrupt 3 will halt a debugger and have no effect if not executed in a  debugger.

I use it extensively in my C/C++ programs as it will not be affected by clearing all breakpoints.

I would like to use it in my PHP exception & error handlers. That way, I can just insert it & forget about it. I can then add & remove breakpoints depending on what I am testing, without affecting those interrupts and be sure that my IDE will always halt if my code encounters a problem at line with such an interrupt.

Can it be done?

Comment: The short answer is no. The PHP code is not compiled to executable code

Comment: Since PHP 5.6 you have a builtin phpdbg interactive debugger [(source)](http://php.net/manual/en/debugger-about.php). I've never used it but, if such thing can be done, this is probably what you need to check first.

Answer (score 3):

`xdebug_break()` is what you need, however in order to use you need to have the xdebug debugger properly setup.

From xdebug [documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions) :

> `bool xdebug_break()`
>   Emits a breakpoint to the debug client.

Comment: Of course, Xdebug is a third-party extension that's normally not installed on production servers so you can't just call `xdebug_break()` in your code and forget it.

Comment: Agreed (+1). But I can always wrap it. I already do a few things based on getting the hostname & checking for `localhost` (because I don't want to rely on even a single constant, which I might forget to set). This does look a good solution for me

Comment: @Mawg It's alright. I was under the impression that you wanted something more similar to the C/C++ technique, i.e., something that didn't have any impact on production. Just don't forget the wrap or your code will throw `Fatal error: Call to undefined function xdebug_break()` ;-)

Comment: Well, I can wrap it in a function, but, as you say, the call to a function that does nothing will affect produciton code. I can live with that, since it's only in error branches.